# Wordpress: Comments keep showing on the page

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have this code to display posts from specific category. It works perfectly fine but the problem is it keeps showing the comments section below where ever i paste the shortcode. Discussion: Allow comments is unchecked.
Please help.
Thanks.

```
<?php
            function get_blog_post_category(){ 
            global $post;
            global $post_id;
            $content = "";
            $content .= '<div class="blog_post_wrap">';  
                    $content .= '<ul class="blog_post_ul">';  
                    $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'category' => 10, 'orderby' =>   'date', 'order' => 'ASC', 'paged' => $paged );
                    $posts = get_posts( $args );
                       foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata($post);

                        $content .= '<li class="col-md-3 blog_post_li">';   
                           $content .= '<a href="'.get_post_permalink().'">';  
                             $content .= '<div class="blog_single_post_wrap"> ';  

                                $post_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_to_use->ID);
                                if ($post_image_id) {
                                $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_image_id, 'post-thumbnail', false);
                                if ($thumbnail) (string)$thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];
                                }

                                $content .= '<div class="blog_image" style="background-image:url('.$thumbnail.')"></div>';

                                //$content .= '<div class="blog_post_images">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail') . '</div>'; 
                                $content .= '<div class="blog_posting_wrap">';
                                $content .= '<div class="blog_time_date">' . get_the_time(get_option('date_format'));
                                $content .= '<span class="blog_viewed">' . getPostViews(get_the_ID()) . '</span>';
                                $content .= '</div>';                         
                                $content .= '<div class="blog_title">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';                         
                                $content .= '<div class="blog_expert">' .  get_the_excerpt() . '</div>';                                          
                                $content .= '</div>';
                              $content .= '</div>';  
                            $content .= '</a>';    
                        $content .= '</li>';

                    endforeach;
                    $content .= '</ul>';
            $content .= '</div>';
            return $content;
            }
             add_shortcode('iu_blog_posts_eng', 'get_blog_post_category');  


             ?>
```

Comment: Did you disallow comments only in the general settings or in the page where you're using this code? Because if you're using a page template, you need to deactivate comments there too. Kinda silly that they have a global setting for that but it doesn't really work as it should :\

Comment: The problem lies in the file in which you are trying to display this code. Try to check that file whether it is allowing comments or not

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking allow comments will not let the users to comment on future posts but before you changed the setting, few of posts are of past so you need to manually change the comment_status like this :

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_status="closed";
```

Comment: run this query inside your phpmyadmin database